# Advantage of loading all css or javascript in one file

Tags: javascript, css, httprequest

I'm actually working on a big project with a custom MVC.
We have a class that loads all modules config, this contains an array of css and javascript necessaries.

I favor to get contents of all css and load into one to reduce HTTP request in my header.
I doubt after seeing similar MVC to  I dunno if it has any disadvantage

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have a max parralels connexion limit (to one domain) so yes, it's better to load a single file for css or js.

An other solution is to have multiple subdomains like and download content from them:

```
a.mydomain.com
b.mydomain.com
c.mydomain.com
```